# Kendo Ui tabstrip selection issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am learning a kendo tabstrip, when I create a tabstrip by using the sample provided in the [link](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/tabstrip/index)  in a new mvc project it is working. I can move to different tab and can see the content, but when I integrated to the existing project, it is not working. Control is coming and tabs are visible, but not traversing to different tabs, I can see the URL changing like #Parameter-2, #Parameter-3 etc while traversing. If this is the case what should i check for rectifying problems?

Comment: It's strage behavior. Have you check your console if there is any error?

Comment: It is related to some jquery bundling, we have to refer all the library required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is related to some jquery bundling, we have to refer all the library required